# Can't turn off Find my Iphone with old apple id password in order to delete account from my iphone

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, find-my-iphone, activation-lock

I'm trying to change the Apple ID on my iPhone 4 to match my iCloud one (already changed Apple ID here) but it keeps asking me for the password linked to the old ID to turn off find my iphone (activation lock), in order to delete the old apple ID account from the phone.

I need to do this so I can sign in again with my new ID. This password of course won't work as the password has already been changed on icloud so the old email address/ID (now showing in the pop up box) doesn't exist!

How can I change my Apple ID?

Comment: Just to confirm, did you try entering the old password?

Comment: turn off find my iPhone from the web - https://www.icloud.com/#find

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous what you're asking - you say that you have two apple IDs, then after that you say that the password has already been changed on iCloud, which contradicts your first statement.